# Dynamically choose ember adapter in ember store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is it possible to dynamically choose between adapters from the ember store or elsewhere in an Ember App? I am implementing offline behavior for my ember app where when offline, the app should utilize the offline adapter to pull data from browser storage.

Where would be the best place to put this logic?

I know there is an adapter property on DS.Store where you can specify a custom adapter (http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#property_defaultAdapter), but I have not been able to get it to work.

Example:

*app/adapters/custom.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Store.extend({

  adapter: 'custom',
});
```

*app/store.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Adapter.extend({

  pathForType: function(type) {
    debugger; //Never goes in here
  },
});
```

What I'm looking to do is something like this:

```
export default DS.Store.extend({
  offlineService: Ember.inject.service('offlineService') //Service to detect if app has network connection      

  adapter: function() {
    if (this.get('offlineService.isOffline') {
      return 'offlineAdapter'
    } else {
      return 'application'
    }
  }.property('offlineService.isOffline')
});
```

Is something along those lines even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want robust offline behavior consider `ServiceWorker`. Otherwise, I think you are looking for an `if` statement in your adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this today is to override the `adapterFor` method:

```
export default DS.Store.extend({
  offlineService: Ember.inject.service('offlineService') //Service to detect if app has network connection      

  adapterFor(modelName) {
    if (this.get('offlineService.isOffline') {
      return this.offlineAdapterFor(modelName);
    } else {
      return this._super(modelName); // use default logic, i.e. adapters/<modelname> file
    }
  },

  offlineAdapterFor(modelName) {
    // your logic here ...
  }
});
```

NOTE: This is a private API. There is no guarantee this will continue to work in future versions of Ember Data.

Documentation:
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_adapterFor

Comment: Totally makes sense. Also `adapterFor` and `serializerFor` have just been made public methods! https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3941